# Navigating to a p-tabview on button click

Tags: angular, primeng

I'm new to the angular and primeNg.

I have details.component.html and there is a button called "start session" in my nav bar. I also have a `<p-tabView>` component in the same file.

I want to show the `<p-tabView>` component when I click the "start session" button.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

if I understand correctly, you just need to render your component by clicking on the button.
in this case you need:

1. hang an event handler on the button

   `<button (click)='yourButtonHandler()/>`
2. create a variable that the element will depend on

   `isTabviewExist = false`
3. create function that will handle click on your button

   `yourButtonHandler() { this.isTabviewExist  = true }`
4. add condition to component

   `<p-tabView *ngIf=isTabviewExist />`

Comment: That will show the tab sure, but my tab is at somewhere down in the site, I want to get it to the screen when I clicked the button